# ftplib retrbinary in paramiko?

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I am working on paramiko sftp. Is there any function similar to the `ftplib` `retrbinary` function in paramiko?

My project already supports ftp and there data is stored in memory using `cStringIO` and then `retrbinary` and `storebinary` are used for accessing it. I have to do the same with sftp using paramiko but it does not support these functions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `retrbinary` function, because SSH treats *all* files as binary.

FTP on the other hand, treats files as textfiles by default, translating line endings, so a separate `retrbinary` was added to prevent that translation for binary files.

To quote from the [`SFTPClient.file()` method](http://lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SFTPClient-class.html#file):

> The mode indicates how the file is to be opened: `'r'` for reading, `'w'` for writing (truncating an existing file), `'a'` for appending, `'r+'` for reading/writing, `'w+'` for reading/writing (truncating an existing file), `'a+'` for reading/appending. The python `'b'` flag is ignored, since SSH treats all files as binary.